# Close popup window opened by a different domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have a link in abc domain which opens a popup window and opens a page in a different domain. I need to add a button on the popup which calls window.close() and closes it via javascript. Is is even doable? can I close a popup using windo.close which has been opened by a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
function openWin(){
   myWindow=window.open("http://www.google.co.uk","","width=200,height=100");
}

function closeWin(){
  if(myWindow){
    myWindow.close();
   }
}
```

hooked up to these buttons:

```
<input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWin()" />
<input type="button" value="Close 'myWindow'" onclick="closeWin()" />
```

it's a tad crude but should work... I'd also make it unobtrusive if I were you, I've used obtrusive code just to get an answer to you quickly

Comment: He means in the window opened to the other domain, have it contain a "close" button. Not buttons on his page that close the opened window.